# asp 301 redirect with cases not working

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

I have been following a guide in a Danish CMS regarding 301 redirects, but they won't do any kind of support on this topic. I am not good in .asp and the things i tried which i could imagine the problem would be.

The problem is that the cases do not work, everything is just redirected to the frontpage and not to the specific link i stated.

```
Dim BadURLAll, BadURLPath, BadURLParam, RedirectTo
BadURLAll        = LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_URL"))
BadURLAll        = Right(BadURLAll, (Len(BadURLAll) - (Instr(BadURLAll, chr(59)))))
if LEFT(BadURLAll,7) = "http://" then
                         BadURLAll = Mid(BadURLAll, 8)
end if
Pos = Instr(BadURLAll, "/")
if Pos > 0 then
                         BadURLAll = Mid(BadURLAll,Pos)
end if
BadURLPath    = BadURLAll
Pos = Instr(BadURLAll, "?")
if Pos > 0 then
                         BadURLParam = Mid(BadURLAll,Pos)
                         BadURLPath    = Mid(BadURLAll,1, Pos-1)
end if
if Right(BadURLPath,1) = "/" then
                         BadURLPath = Mid(BadURLPath,1, LEN(BadURLPath)-1)
end if
RedirectTo = ""
SELECT CASE BadURLPath

Case "/index.php?gid=6&pid=19"      RedirectTo = "http://bodymindcompany.dk/shop/transportable-brikse-4c1.html"
Case "/index.php?gid=8&pid=19"      RedirectTo = "http://bodymindcompany.dk/shop/stationaere-brikse-166c1.html"
Case "/index.php?gid=2&pid=40"      RedirectTo = "http://bodymindcompany.dk/shop/massagestole-5c1.html"
Case "/index.php?gid=5&pid=19"      RedirectTo = "http://bodymindcompany.dk/shop/tilbehoer-til-brikse-11s.html"

END SELECT
if RedirectTo <> "" then 
                         Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
                         Response.AddHeader "Location", RedirectTo
                         Response.End                                                          
else 
                         %>
                         <html>
                         <head>
                         <title>Siden blev ikke fundet / The page you are looking for has been moved</title>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                         <center>
                         <h2>Siden blev ikke fundet / The page has been moved</h2><br><br>
                         </center>
                         </body>
                         </html>
<%end if%>
```

Can anybody helm me out here?

Best

Klaus Andersen

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from your code....

.... how about using something like this:

```
Dim arrOld
Dim arrNew

arrOld = Array ("gid=1&pid=1", "gid=2&pid=2")
arrNew = Array ("page1.asp", "page2.asp")

Dim strParams, strNewPage

strParams = Request.QueryString

For intX = LBound (arrOld) to UBound (arrOld)
    if arrOld (intX) = strParams then
        strNewPage = arrNew (intX)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Response.Write "strParams=" & strParams & "<br>"
Response.Write "strNewPage=" & strNewPage & "<br>"
```

NOTE: array size of "arrOld" and "arrNew" must be the same!